# Не понимаю как исправить ошибку NameError: name 'connection' is not defined

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Начал изучать SQL, при попытке подключения к БД вылетает такая ошибка NameError: name 'connection' is not defined
Предоставляю код:

```
import psycopg2
from auth_data import host, password, db_name, user


def add_to_db():
    global connection
    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password, database=db_name)

        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM records")
            connection.commit()
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            return result
    except Exception as _ex:
        print(f'[INFO] Error while working with PostgreSQL {_ex}')
    finally:
        if connection:
            connection.close()
            print(f'[INFO] PostgreSQL connection closed')

add_to_db()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас попробовал повторить данный код. И ошибка вылезает, когда введены неверные данные для подключения. Так что советую проверить логин/пароль/базу и тд. Место объявления `connection` никак не повлияло на выполнение.

Comment: Да. Нашел ошибку в данных. Почему-то решил, что database - это название таблицы. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @shezyy не за что, рад был помочь:)

Comment: Но первая ошибка-то была NameError!

Comment: @nchistov, я с вами согласен, что так указывать переменные не корректно, но эта ошибка появилась из-за того, что был вызван exception, внутри которого connection не определяется, но главная ошибка то заключается в самом подключении к БД

Comment: @nchistov так он с ней и помог

Answer (score 2):

У вас переменная `connection` создаётся внутри `try` а используется внутри `finally` так что надо её создать перед всем этим:

```py
import psycopg2
from auth_data import host, password, db_name, user


def add_to_db():
    global connection
    connection = None  # <--- Вот здесь

    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password, database=db_name)

        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM records")
            connection.commit()
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            return result
    except Exception as _ex:
        print(f'[INFO] Error while working with PostgreSQL {_ex}')
    finally:
        if connection:
            connection.close()
            print(f'[INFO] PostgreSQL connection closed')

add_to_db()
```

Comment: Попробовал. Теперь выдает ошибку:  `psycopg2.OperationalError`

Comment: @shezyy ну это уже другая проблема.